# How do I make my water see-through completely?

Tags: modeling, python, animation, uv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wVkr.jpg)

[image]

[image: I would like it to look like this]

I have some water I made and need it to be see through so you can see the bottom of the "pool" here are the settings I have and I would like it to look like the image above^

[image]

Comment: A naive beginner's guess - Alpha level, could it be?